# Swiffy content stopped working suddenly

Tags: javascript, html, google-swiffy

I converted about 25 swf's to html5 using google swiffy a few days ago. We tested all conversions on desktop and mobile Ipads 1-4 with safari. They all worked a few days ago.

Today while testing it seems they have all broke sudenly. No changes on our server.
The next buttons do not function anymore.

http://www.wisc-online.com/Objects/ACE2303/old/index.html

Im curious if google updated their runtime.js file. 
https://www.gstatic.com/swiffy/v5.3/runtime.js

Has anyone had a similar experience and how did you solve it?

Thanks for your help!

Josh

Link to our page in question
http://www.wisc-online.com/Objects/ACE2303/old/index.html
Must test on ipad to see it now work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same thing happened to me buddy !

They changed the Swiffy 5.3 version all right !

what I did to get it to work back was by pointing to a Swiffy 5.2 .js that I saved before !

This was frustrating because I put in some hours to troubleshoot

This Swiffy convertion is really great but I don't get it why it's doing this with version 5.3

I just pointed to a Swiffy version 5.2 .js and it works great even has the code output in the html form version 5.3

Comment: It is unfortunate that the conversion tool uses the live web service and there is no way to select "Use version x.x" in the conversion. I too keep a copy of previous versions of the runtime, but I hit problems when converting a batch of stuff for a single project & the runtime updates inthe middle of this work. :/